Why doesn’t VS code find Python?
The vs code and Python are installed and when I press ctrl+shift+P to choose interpreter python is not listed.
What can be the problem?

Python extension and Python interpreter are 2 different things.

first :
you have to install python on your system or virtual machine
here to download python
you can use documentation > beginners guide to read installations tutorial
then open vs code
go to extension menu and install python extension
make sure that python is added to your system environments
in first stage of installation there is a check box about this
